# Changing Title of Google Calendar event using Google Calendar API v3 and Data Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am able to successfully pull events from my google calendar using an API key. 

**The events are shown on my webpage as follows:**
5/31/2016 9:00:00 AM - 5/31/2016 12:00:00 PM
Event Title: Staff Meeting
Description: Weekly staff meeting

I would like to set the color for "Event Title" to red through the code behind file. I have tried to change it in line in my dt.Rows.Add but have been unsuccessful. Is there a way for me to change it in the code behind so that just the "Event Title:" is effected?

**aspx code**

```
<div>        
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCalEvents">
        <ItemTemplate>                
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblItemTemplate" Visible="true"> <%# Eval("Summary") %> </asp:Label>    
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTesting" ForeColor="#660000" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="15px" Visible="false"></asp:Label>        
</div>
```

**aspx.cs code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    GetCalEvents();
}
private void GetCalEvents()
{        
   var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
      ApiKey = "MY API KEY",
      ApplicationName = "Events Calendar",
   });

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("Summary");

   EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("Google Calendar");
   request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
   request.TimeMax = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
   request.SingleEvents = true;
   request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

   Events events = request.Execute();
   if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
   {
      foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
      {
         string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();

         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
         {
            when = eventItem.Start.Date;
         }

         dt.Rows.Add(string.Format(when + " - " + eventItem.End.DateTime + "<br /><strong>" + "Event Title:" + "&nbsp;" + eventItem.Summary + "</strong>" + "<br /><strong>Event:</strong><br />" + eventItem.Description + "<hr/>"));
      }

      rptCalEvents.DataSource = dt;
      rptCalEvents.DataBind();
   }
   else
   {
      lblTesting.Visible = true;
      lblTesting.Text = "<strong>" + "No Upcoming Events for Today!!!" + "</strong>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the title of your event?  Is it inside of a label?  If it is just get a handle of the label and change it's color: `Label t = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTitle"); t.ForeColor=Color.Red`

Comment: It's in a data repeater <%# Eval("Summary") %> on the aspx page and on the aspx.cs it's in here dt.Rows.Add(string.Format( **Event Title:**);

Comment: Right but you should bind it to something like a label, by doing that you can take advantage of events such as ItemCommand, etc.  In your case you have `lblItemTemplate` just capture that label and set the background or foreground color.

Comment: I tried that but it changes the color for the whole event, which is not what I want. I want to change the color for just the actual word "**Event Title:**". Is there a way I could do that from my code behind, since that's something I hard coded in?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap in a `<font>` tag:

```
dt.Rows.Add(string.Format(when + " - " + eventItem.End.DateTime + "<br /><font color=\"red\"><strong>" + "Event Title:" + "&nbsp;" + eventItem.Summary + "</strong></font>" + "<br /><strong>Event:</strong><br />" + eventItem.Description + "<hr/>"));
```

Comment: I tried that but the font tag isn't working when I try it. :-(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got it working. I figured out what I was doing wrong. Had to break apart the code.